# Segue in cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't send data

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue, didselectrowatindexpath

In my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I try to set some `data` and finally do a `segue`.

Code looks like **this**:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, DidSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)


    otherName = groupIds[indexPath.row] as! String

    otherActualName = groupNames[indexPath.row] as! String

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("matchToConversation", sender: self)
}
```

`otherName` and `otherActualName` are declared as global variables.

If I put `breakpoints` the global variables are getting their right values. If I don't it doesn't work. I think my Segue is triggered before the data is assigned since they are products of a `PFQuery`.

I tried to use the `prepareForSegue` function, but I'm not sure how to use it here. Any Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prepareForSegue` will let you assign those variables to your next view controller. Let's say you're pushing a `viewController` and you want to pass those 2 params, you could use prepare for segue this way.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)     
{
  if segue.identifier == "YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER" {
    let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! YourNextViewController
    destinationController.otherName = self.otherName
    destinationController.otherActualName = self.otherActualName
  }
}
```

If your `groupIds` and `groupNames` arrays are populated when `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` is called, the values should be passed no problem.

What you need is define your new view controller like so

```
class YourNextViewController: UIViewController
{
  var otherName: String? 
  var otherActualName: String?
}
```

That way you can pass your values in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: `prepareForSegue` should be called in the "origin view controller", so the same view controller that calls `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: so its a function i declare right after my didSelectRowAtIndexPath. How do i call it from here? Is this automatically implemented?

Comment: This tutorial should be able to help you: http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/